# A question on the greatest common divisor of integers and their divisor sum

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum

Suppose that $x, y, z$ are positive integers.

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the *sum of the divisors* of $x$, and let $\gcd(y, z)$ be the *greatest common divisor* of $y$ and $z$.

Here is my question:

> If the following divisibility constraints hold:
>   $$\gcd(X, Y) = 1$$
>   $$\gcd(X, \sigma(X)) = 1$$
>   $$\gcd(Y, \sigma(Y)) = 1$$
>   $$\gcd(XY, \sigma(XY)) = 1$$
>   does it follow that either
>   $$\gcd(X, \sigma(Y)) = 1$$
>   or
>   $$\gcd(Y, \sigma(X)) = 1?$$

Comment: one or the other or is this two question? X = 7 y = 13 has gcd(X,sumY) = 7 but it has gcd(y, sum X) = 1.

Comment: @fleablood, thank you for your comment.  For $X = 7$ and $Y = 13$, the fourth condition in the hypothesis:
$$\gcd(XY, \sigma(XY)) = 1$$
is not satisfied, as
$$\gcd(7\cdot{13}, \sigma(7\cdot{13})) = \gcd(7\cdot{13}, 8\cdot{14}) = 7 \neq 1.$$

Comment: Any way, to answer your question, I am looking for a proof or a disproof of the *disjunction*
$$\{\gcd(X,\sigma(Y))=1\} \lor \{\gcd(Y,\sigma(X)) = 1\}$$
given that the four conditions in the hypothesis are satisfied.

Comment: It appears that both $\gcd(x, \sigma(y)) = 1$ and  $\gcd(y, \sigma(s)) = 1$

Comment: @WillJagy, care to outline a proof for what you have in mind?  =)

Comment: I gave a counter example of them not both having to be true.  I don't know if they can both be false however.

Comment: You have given the appearance that you did not check this for small $x,y$ with a computer program. You should learn to do that. I just wrote a program for $1 \leq x < y \leq 2500$ and both gcd's are always 1. This is such a strong outcome that a proof may be possible. Next is to see if there are any genuine restrictions on the factorization of, say $y.$

Comment: @fleablood: Your purported "counterexample" of $X=7$ and $Y=13$ is **not actually** one, as the fourth condition of the hypothesis is not satisfied.  See my first comment (below yours) above.

Comment: Perhaps no genuine restrictions on factoring just one of $x,y$ as x: 187 =  11 17   y: 245 =  5 7^2 gcd(x,ys): 1 gcd(y,xs): 1  works.

Comment: Okay, agreed @WillJagy.

Comment: @WillJagy: I have just finished a proof attempt in an answer below the fold.  Mind having a quick look at it?  =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) on the greatest common divisor, we use the following property:

> **Property G** $$\gcd(a, b \cdot c) = 1 \iff \{\gcd(a, b) = 1 \land \gcd(a, c) = 1\}.$$

In particular, we obtain
$$\gcd(XY, \sigma(XY)) = 1 \iff \gcd(XY, \sigma(X)\sigma(Y)) = 1$$
(since $\gcd(X,Y) = 1$ and $\sigma$ is *weakly multiplicative*)
$$\iff \{\gcd(XY, \sigma(X)) = 1 \land \gcd(XY, \sigma(Y)) = 1\}$$
(using **Property G**)
$$\iff \{\gcd(X, \sigma(X)) = 1\} \land \{\gcd(Y, \sigma(X)) = 1\} \land \{\gcd(X, \sigma(Y)) = 1\} \land \{\gcd(Y, \sigma(Y)\} = 1\}$$
(using **Property G**)
$$\iff \{\gcd(Y, \sigma(X)) = 1\} \land \{\gcd(X, \sigma(Y)) = 1\}$$
(since $\gcd(X,\sigma(X)) = 1$ and $\gcd(Y,\sigma(Y)) = 1$).

**QED**

I hope that everything that I have written out is correct!  =)

Comment: yes, that works. Before I went to the post office, i deliberately ran the program without the final condition (out of four) and it quickly gave  examples, such as $x=2, y=3,$ where things went wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much for the confirmation, @WillJagy!  =)

Comment: Notice that you do not need the second and third of your four hypotheses.